# spring mvc: why its generating duplicate value attribute?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to set a value in form tag using form:input but on html its generating multiple attributes how to fix it?

```
<form:input class="text" type="text" value="Login ID" path="dCode"/>
```

the generated code is

```
<input id="dCode" name="dCode" value="Login ID" class="text" type="text" value=""/>
```

how to fix the above jsp code so that generated html code in browser has just a single value attribute having value "Login ID"

Comment: what value is displayed in JSP from that input box?Is it "Login ID" Or Blank

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Spring's

```
<form:input>
```

tag does not have attribute "Value". I dont know the exact reason but my guess is perhaps it could have developed for saving the data instead of edit.

In your case, if you have used **

```
<form:form>
```

tag, then there is no need to use

```
 <form:input>
```

tag as spring by default considers normal **

```
 <input>
```

tags as

```
 <form:input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring's `<form:input>` tag [does not have](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input) a `class`, `type` nor `value` attribute. The tag uses the `path` attribute to determine what the value of the input should be when it generates the real HTML. The `path` attribute points to a field on the form backing bean.

In your application, the `dCode` field on your bean has no value (it's probably null) - because the HTML value is being output as `""`. If you wish to set this to **Login ID** then you must initialise the `dCode` field to this string.

```
private String dCode = "Login ID";
```

Then remove the `class`, `type` and `value` attributes from your `<form:input>` tag. You can add css styling via the `cssClass` and `cssStyle` attributes (which are resolved to the `class` and `style` HTML attributes respectively).